# strcmp() segfaults, no idea why?

Tags: c

I'm working on an assigment for college and this is my last function I need to implement. Pardon me for it being on another language, but I believe it provides little context to it all. It is supposed to pick up info from another file and update an original file with data about flights and seats using graphs. My issue is the strcmp.

```
aresta_grafo **atualiza_lugares(char *ficheiro, grafo *g, int *n)

{

    if(!ficheiro||!g||!n) return NULL;

    FILE* f=fopen(ficheiro,"r");

    if(!f) return NULL;

    char voo[20];

    char codigo[20];

    int lugares;

    int k=0;



    aresta_grafo** aresta_aux=(aresta_grafo**)malloc(sizeof(aresta_grafo*));

    if (!aresta_aux) {

        free(aresta_aux);

        return NULL;

    }



    while(fgets(voo,20,f)!=NULL){

        _Bool flag=0;

        strcpy(codigo,strtok(voo,","));

        printf("%s",voo);

        lugares=atoi(strtok(NULL,","));

        printf("%d",lugares);

        for (int i = 0; i < g->tamanho; i++)

        {

            if(flag) break;

            for (int j = 0; j < g->nos[i]->tamanho; j++)

            {

                if(flag) break;

                if(strcmp(g->nos[i]->arestas[j]->codigo,codigo)==0){

                    if(lugares==0){

                        if(k!=0) 

                            aresta_aux=realloc(aresta_aux,(k+1)*sizeof(aresta_grafo*));

                        aresta_aux[k]=g->nos[i]->arestas[j];

                        g->nos[i]->arestas[j]=NULL;

                        k++;

                    } else g->nos[i]->arestas[j]->lugares=lugares;

                    flag=1;

                }

            }

        }

        *n=k;

    }

    fclose(f);
```

I've checked other threads, but I tried everything and still segfaults, I suspect it has to do with the strtok, but I can't tell why because prints don't work.

Comment: Is this a C++ course or a C course? If it is for a C++ course your instructor might be surprised to see that the code is effectively in pure C.

Comment: Are you asking a C or C++ question? The tags say C++ but the code seems like C to me.

Comment: Assuming it's the call `strcmp(g->nos[i]->arestas[j]->codigo,codigo)` that crashes (which you have verified with a debugger I hope?) then there's a lot of pointers in that call. Are all of them valid?

Comment: Also, please post a [mcve].  Where is the final return value for `atualiza_lugares()`?  If your function ends on that `fclose`, then there is nothing we can reason from your program, since you've invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: There are also many other suspect things with your code. And also it's not valid C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with this, but I think what's going wrong is that there's no null terminator on your strings read from the file. `strcmp` and `strcpy` are designed to work with strings that have a trailing null terminator, aka `'\0'`. Your memory buffers don't have this. So what I would recommend doing is using `memcmp` and `memcpy` instead, which allow you to set a memory size (in this case 20).

The other thing you could do is force a null terminator to the end of your string by changing your buffer sizes to 21 and setting the value of `buffer[20]` to be `'\0'`. I would recommend against this though since it will fail if the number of bytes read from the file is not exactly 20.

EDIT: But since this is c++ just use file streams and `std::string` to make your life easier. Don't mess with the old c programs unless you have to (or really know what you're doing).

Comment: How about with new C programs? Wrote some last week.

Comment: While being tagged as C++, the code itself isn't C++, it's plain C. Either the OP mistagged the question, don't know what language it actually is, or has been misled.

Comment: That's true, but I'm suggesting a solution in the case that OP is actually using C++. The solution for plain C is also provided.

Comment: In C++, the C-Style strings must have terminating nul character.  It's part of the interface for the C language functions that got ported into C++.